# Why I cant access this private variable?

Tags: c++, oop, binary-search-tree, private, treenode

Im trying to made BST with OOP and my lecturer want me to made the node into class so I made this code

node.h

```
#ifndef node_h
#define node_h
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node{
    public : 
        Node();
        Node(Node* left_node, Node* right_node, string newname, string newaddress, int age);
        ~Node();
        // Getter
        Node* GetLeft();
        Node* GetRight();
        string GetName();
        string GetAddress();
        int GetAge();
        // Setter
        void SetName(string newname);
        void SetAddress(string newaddress);
        void SetAge(int newage);
        void SetLeft(Node* newnode);
        void SetRight(Node* newnode);
    private :
        string name,address;
        int age;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
};

#endif
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

Node::Node(){
    Node::name="";
    Node::address="";
    Node::age=0;
    Node::left=NULL;
    Node::right=NULL;
};

Node::Node(Node* left_node, Node* right_node, string newname, string newaddress, int newage){
    Node::left = left_node;
    Node::right = right_node;
    Node::name = newname;
    Node::address = newaddress;
    Node::age = newage;
};

Node::~Node(){

}

// Getter
Node* Node::GetLeft(){
    return left;
};

Node* Node::GetRight(){
    return right;
};

string Node::GetName(){
    return name;
};

string Node::GetAddress(){
    return address;
};

int Node::GetAge(){
    return age;
};

// Setter
void Node::SetName(string newname){
    Node::name = newname;
};

void Node::SetAddress(string newaddress){
    Node::address = newaddress;
};

void Node::SetAge(int newage){
    Node::age = newage;
};

void SetLeft(Node* newnode){
    Node::left = newnode;
};

void SetRight(Node* newnode){
    Node::right = newnode;
};
```

but when I run it i got invalid use of non-static data member

Anyone can help what should I do so I can set left node and right node?
NB : Im not so good with OOP, just start to studying about it, sorry for the bad english too

Comment: Inside your function bodies: `Node::name` -> `name` etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Instead of "when I run it i got invalid use of non-static data member" say: when I *compile* it I get: [copy-paste your error message here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
void SetLeft(Node* newnode){
    Node::left = newnode;
};
```

This `SetLeft` is not a member of `Node`, so it cannot access private members of a `Node`.

You probably meant:

```
void Node::SetLeft(Node* newnode){
```

etc.  The `SetRight` just below has the same problem too.

Comment: I have change my code like what you said but when I compile it I get: [c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16` collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status]

Comment: @Alv you need a `main` function

Answer (score 0):

Write `SetLeft` with scope resolution operator in `node.cpp`. It is supposed to be written as : `void Node::SetLeft(parameters)` and `SetRight` is also supposed to be written in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
Node::left = newnode;
```

use:

```
this->left = newnode;
```

By using Node::left you're trying to access a static member, which is not declared.

'this' reflects to the class instance you're working with!

Comment: i got "invalid use of 'this' in non-member function"

Comment: In a member function of `Node` it is valid to use `Node::left` to refer to private member variable `left`

Comment: Ah, my mistake then! Got confused a bit with C#. Thanks for correcting.